# "Faking" axis ticks and labels with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a figure in which every dimension of a multi-dimensional data set is plotted against every other in a grid of subplots. Here is what I have so far:

[image]

The x dimension is determined by the subplot column and the y dimension is determined by the row. When the dimensions are equal a 1-d histogram with density on the y axis is plotted, otherwise a 2d histogram with density mapped to color is used. When creating each subplot I share the x-axis with the first plot in that column (using the `sharex` argument in the `Figure.add_subplot` function). Y axes are shared similarly, except with the 1d histograms.

This works well to keep the axes on the same scale, but you can see the problem on the upper left. Since most axes are the same across rows and columns I only have tick marks on the bottom and left parts of the figure. The problem is that the top left subplot has a different y scale than the rest of its row.

I want to actually have ticks for the y axes of the other subplots on the row, applied to the top-left subplot, *without* changing that subplot's y limits. Getting y labels from the 2nd subplot in the row and setting them on the first works, but actually changing the positions of the ticks doesn't as the limits of the axes are not the same. I can't work out how to set the tick positions in relative terms aside from explicitly transforming points from the scale of one plot to the other.

EDIT: Since someone asked, here's a basic version of the code used to generate this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

def matrix_plot(figure, data, limits, labels):
    """
    Args:
        figure: matplotlib Figure
        data: numpy.ndarray, points/observations in rows
        limits: list of (min, max) values for axis limits
        labels: list of labels for each dimension
    """

    # Number of dimensions (data columns)
    ndim = data.shape[1]

    # Create KDE objects
    density = [ gaussian_kde(data[:,dim]) for dim in range(ndim) ]

    # Keep track of subplots
    plots = np.ndarray((ndim, ndim), dtype=object)

    # Loop through dimensions twice
    # dim1 goes by column
    for dim1 in range(ndim):
        # dim2 goes by row
        for dim2 in range(ndim):

            # Index of plot
            i = dim2 * ndim + dim1 + 1

            # Share x-axis with plot at top of column
            # Share y-axis with plot at beginning of row, unless that
            #    plot or current plot is a 1d plot
            kwargs = dict()
            if dim2 > 0:
                kwargs['sharex'] = plots[0][dim1]
                if dim1 > 0 and dim1 != dim2:
                    kwargs['sharey'] = plots[dim2][0]
            elif dim1 > 1:
                kwargs['sharey'] = plots[dim2][1]

            # Create new subplot
            # Pass in shared axis arguments with **kwargs
            plot = figure.add_subplot(ndim, ndim, i, **kwargs)
            plots[dim2][dim1] = plot

            # 1d density plot
            if dim1 == dim2:

                # Space to plot over
                x = np.linspace(limits[dim][0], limits[dim][1], 100)

                # Plot filled region
                plot.set_xlim(limits[dim])
                plot.fill_between(x, density[dim].evaluate(x))

            # 2d density plot
            else:

                # Make histogram
                h, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(data[:,dim1],
                    data[:,dim2], range=[limits[dim1], limits[dim2]],
                    bins=250)

                # Set zero bins to NaN to make empty regions of
                #   plot transparent
                h[h == 0] = np.nan

                # Plot without grid
                plot.imshow(h.T, origin='lower',
                    extent=np.concatenate((limits[dim1], limits[dim2])),
                    aspect='auto')
                plot.grid(False)

            # Ticks and labels of except on figure edges
            plot.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', left='off',
                right='off', bottom='off', top='off', labelleft='off',
                labelbottom='off')
            if dim1 == 0:
                plot.tick_params(axis='y', left='on', labelleft='on')
                plot.set_ylabel(labels[dim2])
            if dim2 == self._ndim - 1:
                plot.tick_params(axis='x', bottom='on', labelbottom='on')
                plot.set_xlabel(labels[dim1])

        # Tight layout
        figure.tight_layout(pad=.1, h_pad=0, w_pad=0)
```

And here's what I get when I try to copy tick positions and labels from the y-axis of the 2nd plot in the first row to the first plot:

```
plots[0][0].set_yticks(plots[0][1].get_yticks())
plots[0][0].set_yticklabels(plots[0][1].get_yticklabels())
```

[image]

Notice how it assigns tick positions on an absolute scale which is much higher than the scale of the density plot. The axis limits expand to show the ticks so the actual density curve gets squashed down to the bottom. Also, the labels do not show up.

Comment: Perhaps you can fake it with [set_yticklabels](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels) and set_yticks

Comment: What code did you use to generate this?  It would help to see how you did it.  Also, not really an answer to your question, but you might try using `scatter_matrix` from [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-tools) - it makes this exact kind of plot and should handle those limits correctly.

Comment: I've edited the question with example code and results with copying ticks from a 2d histogram plot to the top left density plot.

Comment: seaborn PairGrids maintain the ticks and grid lines: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html#plotting-pairwise-relationships-with-pairgrid-and-pairplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ajean's comment for informing me of the `scatter_matrix` function in the `pandas` package, which does more or less what I'm trying to do here. I checked out the source on GitHub and found the part where they "fix" the axes on the top-left plot to correspond to the row's shared y-axis instead of the density axis:

```
if len(df.columns) > 1:
    lim1 = boundaries_list[0]
    locs = axes[0][1].yaxis.get_majorticklocs()
    locs = locs[(lim1[0] <= locs) & (locs <= lim1[1])]
    adj = (locs - lim1[0]) / (lim1[1] - lim1[0])

    lim0 = axes[0][0].get_ylim()
    adj = adj * (lim0[1] - lim0[0]) + lim0[0]
    axes[0][0].yaxis.set_ticks(adj)

    if np.all(locs == locs.astype(int)):
        # if all ticks are int
        locs = locs.astype(int)
    axes[0][0].yaxis.set_ticklabels(locs)
```

Unfortunately it looks like what I was afraid of: there isn't any more elegant way of doing this other than manually transforming tick locations from one range to another. Here's my version, which goes right after the double loop:

```
# Check there are more plots in the row, just in case
if ndim > 1:
    # Get tick locations from 2nd plot in first row
    ticks = np.asarray(plots[0][1].yaxis.get_majorticklocs())

    # Throw out the ones that aren't within the limit
    # (Copied from pandas code, but probably not necessary)
    ticks = ticks[(ticks >= limits[0][0]) & (ticks <= limits[0][1])]

    # Scale ticks to range of [0, 1] (relative to axis limits)
    ticks_scaled = (ticks - limits[0][0]) / (limits[0][1] - limits[0][0])

    # Y limits of top-left density plot (was automatically determined
    #       by matplotlib)
    dlim = plots[0][0].get_ylim()

    # Set the ticks scaled to the plot's own y-axis
    plots[0][0].set_yticks((ticks_scaled * (dlim[1] - dlim[0])) + dlim[0])

    # Set tick labels to their original positions on the 2d plot
    plots[0][0].set_yticklabels(ticks)
```

This gets the results I was looking for.